# Is There a List of Errors in Cartan and Eilenberg's "Homological Algebra"?

Tags: homological-algebra

Is there a list of errors in Cartan and Eilenberg's *Homological Algebra* posted somewhere accessible? The article by Flanders, "Satellites of half exact functors, a correction,"
*Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **15** (1964), 834–837, points out an error in one proof.